# Какой способ использования метода .appendTo() правильнее?

Tags: jquery, append

Способ 1:

```
var $root = "#wrap",
$item1 = "arr111",
$item2 = "arr112",
$item3 = "arr113";
$("#"+$item1+", label[for='"+$item1+"'], #"+$item2+", label[for='"+$item2+"'], #"+$item3+", label[for='"+$item3+"']").appendTo($root);
```

Способ 2:

```
var $root = "#wrap";
arr = ['arr111', 'arr112', 'arr113'];
$.each(arr, function() {
  $("#"+this+", label[for='"+this+"']").appendTo($root);
});
```

Второй мне нравится гораздо больше, но он медленней в 2,5 раза.
Подскажите какой способ архитектурно правильней.

Comment: А каким образом было замеряно что в 2.5 раза медленней? Для тестов скорости нужно по 10 000 раз запускать в цикле код чтобы вычислить его скорость. Кстати а насколько это место критическое, разве оно часто выполняется, чтобы его оптимизировать? Второй вид кода конечно гораздо красивее и читабельнее.

Comment: замерял var time = performance.now();
time = performance.now() - time;
console.log('Время выполнения = ', time);

Comment: место не критичное

Comment: Если место не критичное то общее правило всегда такое что такие места не нужно заранее оптимизировать, особенно если на кону красота кода. Нужно оптимизировать только то что реально занимает значительное время от исполнения всего кода. По поводу замера, то этот замер конечно не точный, т.к. вы наверное замерили только одну итерацию, чтобы точно сравнить время нужно не меньше 1000 раз повторять одно и то же действие, для того чтобы время замеренное было сравнимо с 1 сек.